# Pre carregar imagens com javascript, qual é forma correta de realizar isso?

Tags: javascript

Estou tendo problemas com o carregamento de imagens em servidor.
Gostaria de saber qual é a forma correta de realizar o pre-carregamento dessas imagens.

```
// JavaScript Functions
function sleep (time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

function load(){
    var colors = ["http://meusite.com/pasta/img/playerRightC.png","http://meusite.com/pasta/img/playerLeftC.png","http://meusite.com/pasta/img/playerRight.png","http://meusite.com/pasta/img/playerLeft.png","http://meusite.com/pasta/img/wallpaper01.png","http://meusite.com/pasta/img/cheese.png","http://meusite.com/pasta/img/toca.png","http://meusite.com/pasta/img/help1.png","http://meusite.com/pasta/img/help2.png","http://meusite.com/pasta/img/help3.png","http://meusite.com/pasta/img/cnImg.png"];

    for (color in colors) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = colors[color];
    }

}

load();

sleep(6000).then(() => {
    StartGame(); 
});;


window.addEventListener('keydown', KeyDown, true);
```

Adicionei um delay de 6000ms para iniciar o jogo, assim as imagens poderiam ser carregadas pela função load.

Entretanto, as imagens não são pre-carregadas, ainda há um delay de 0.5ms a 2.0s em conexões mais lentas que tentam jogar o jogo.
Está correta essa forma de carregar as imagens? Tem uma forma mais eficaz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não acho uma boa tentar *adivinhar* o tempo de carregamento das imagens, porque isso pode variar muito dependendo da conexão, peso ou quantidade de imagens.

Você pode criar um `img.onload` para cada imagem. Desta forma, a função `StartGame()` só será chamada após todas as imagens terem sido carregadas.

Crie um contador iniciando em `0`, e à medida em que cada imagem é carregada, irá incrementar o contador e quando ele for igual ao tamanho da array, a função é chamada:

```
function load(){
   var colors = ["http://meusite.com/pasta/img/playerRightC.png","http://meusite.com/pasta/img/playerLeftC.png","http://meusite.com/pasta/img/playerRight.png","http://meusite.com/pasta/img/playerLeft.png","http://meusite.com/pasta/img/wallpaper01.png","http://meusite.com/pasta/img/cheese.png","http://meusite.com/pasta/img/toca.png","http://meusite.com/pasta/img/help1.png","http://meusite.com/pasta/img/help2.png","http://meusite.com/pasta/img/help3.png","http://meusite.com/pasta/img/cnImg.png"];

   var num_imgs = colors.length; // conta a array
   var conta_imgs = 0; // contador
   for (color in colors) {
      img = new Image();

      img.onload = function(){ // evento onload
         conta_imgs++; // incrementa o contador quando uma imagem é carregada
         // quando forem iguais, chama a função
         if(conta_imgs == num_imgs) StartGame();
      }

      img.src = colors[color];
   }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Uma duvida, posso carregar som do formato mp3 dessa forma também?

Comment: Aí eu já não sei. Creio que som funciona a base se streaming, vai tocando à medida que vai sendo carregado... mas não tenho essa certeza.